# delete tag ad-cert

Tags: support, tags

I accidentally made a tag I didnt intend (ad-cert). I intended to retag as ad-certificate-services that already exists. Can someone please delete ad-cert? Or will it disappear on its own accord from some maintenance task perhaps?

Thanks

M

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right: tags automatically disappear if there is no associated post (and if it's not a synonym), but thank you taking the time to let us know!

(Btw, in this case I manually removed it.)